# Resize the box in relation to the text contained inside

Tags: tcolorbox

Two questions:

1. *How can I reduce the size of the box?*
2. *How I can reduce the box in relation to the text contained in the box?*

[image]

Here my MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[lmargin=.8cm, rmargin=.7cm, bmargin=2cm, 
marginparwidth=5.5cm, marginparsep=2em]{geometry} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\tcbset{enhanced,colback=LightGoldenrodYellow,
boxrule=1.1pt, colframe=LightGoldenrodYellow,fonttitle=\bfseries,halign=center,valign=center}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
    lifted shadow={1mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}%
    {black!50!white}]
    \textbf{SVILUPPO IN MULTIPOLI \\DI POTENZIALI NEWTONIANI \\E COULOMBIANI}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: font sizes are no environments

Comment: Btw: `\textsc` on an all-uppercase String does exactly nothing.

Comment: @TeXnician You're absolutely right. I will now change the code. There were two strings because there were two different departments. I didn't even notice it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a \tcbox:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[lmargin=.8cm, rmargin=.7cm, bmargin=2cm,
marginparwidth=5.5cm, marginparsep=2em]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\tcbset{enhanced,
        colback=LightGoldenrodYellow,
        boxrule=1.1pt,
        colframe=LightGoldenrodYellow,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        halign=center,valign=center}

\tcbox[lifted shadow={1mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}%
      {black!50!white}]
{\Huge\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textbf{SVILUPPO IN MULTIPOLI} \\\textbf{DI POTENZIALI NEWTONIANI} \\\textbf{E COULOMBIANI}\end{tabular}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]